# DefaultControllerFactory vs IDependencyResolver

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a little misunderstanding: when we implement IDependencyResolver it means that we can use DI for every part in the project. So even if i don't inherit from DefaultControllerFactory i can build controllers regestering dependencies?

**edits:** i recommend look through all these  [Brad Wilson's posts](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html)
also  [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/21/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-dependencyresolver-and-controlleractivator.aspx)  is useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pedant note first. You cannot inherit from an interface (IDependencyResolver) but I assume you mean implement.

In short you have a choice between using either, you would not use both.  So if you have the resolver set up you do not need to have a controller factory and vice versa.

I have only used DefaultControllerFactory in mvc with castle-windsor.  You will need to be wary of one loose end in using IDependencyResolver if you are using castle-windsor also, there is [no release method](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.ie/2011/02/mvc-30-idependencyresolver-interface-is.html) but there are probably ways around this.

With other frameworks such as [ninject](http://forums.asp.net/t/1818076.aspx/1?DependencyResolver%20why%20is%20this%20preferable%20to%20DefaultControllerFactory) or [unity](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/21/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-dependencyresolver-and-controlleractivator.aspx) IDependencyResolver is sometimes preferable.

Comment: I use ninject. So, the only reason to use one of those is to inject dependencies, right? And I don't need to override GetControllerInstance() method to create controllers?

Comment: I have not experience of this but from reading it seems you are correct.  from the ninject link above, look at the second example in the question.  you might want to look at https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3

Comment: i read the same book as from that example above and because of it the question has occured) other links are also very useful.